# Stream Analytics output to Synapse Analytics in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-stream-analytics, azure-synapse

I'm finding absolutely 0 documentation about how to output from Stream Analytics to Azure Synapse Analytics as an output... I've got it configured in the portal but when I export the template all of the details about this output are lost besides the name.

I tried building it from scratch and there's no documentation at all. How do I write this into an ARM template? I have the following...

```
"outputs": [
    {
        "name": "synapse-output",
        "properties": {
           "datasource": {
               "type": "",
               "properties": {

                }
            }
         }
    }
]
```

And there are no details about how to fill it in... what is the Type for this type of output and how do I even fill in the properties with 0 documentation?

Answer (score 0):

There is a reference for all template resources in microsoft documentation see the [Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs/outputs template reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.streamanalytics/streamingjobs/outputs)

The code to create stream analytics outputs but there is no reference for Azure Synapse Analytics output

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "type": "Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs/outputs",
  "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
  "properties": {
    "datasource": {
      "type": "string",
      "properties": {
      }
    },
    "serialization": {
      "type": "string",
      "properties": {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use refernce function to output the output details

```
"output": {
    "type": "object",
    "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs/outputs', 'JobName', 'outputName'), '2016-03-01', 'Full')]"
}
```